# Plausibility of this submerged smelter design?

Tags: internal-consistency, materials, underwater, metalworking

This design involves a regular smelter, housed in a large water-proof shell that completely covers it. The lower part of the shell would be exposed to the surrounding water. The shell would be filled with air extracted from nautilus-like animals, which will push the water aside. Extra air could be added to the smelter through a pipe under the shell, using bellows. The extra air should, if the shell is strong enough, be forced into the water, allowing air to be added continuously through the smelting process. Could this system be used to smelt metals in useful quantities?

[image]

A sketch of the idea

Comment: Seems, as sketch, more or less workable unit, what is u concern, what do u think may not work here, which doubts u have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some concerns I have about the design:

- You could vent by letting gas escape through the bottom of the shell, but I'm not certain you want your exhaust gasses trying to force their way out past the fire. You could add tall walls around the smelter sides, so that the pressure gradient from bellows, through the furnace, around the tall walls, and down the bottom is always positive.
- The "on" state of the furnace is at least 700 to 800 C (1000 K / 1200  K) (for working with glass and soft metals). That's probably at least 3 times the mean temperature of the surrounding sea water (17 C / 290 K).

  - For each doubling of the temperature, you double the pressure.
  - For each doubling of the pressure, the water column at the bottom moves up or down by $\pm$ 40 feet (~13 meters).
  - When the furnace is quenched, I imagine you'll need to be quick on the bellows to keep the chamber full of air, or sea water will rush in to the quickly cooling/pressure-dropping chamber and possibly ruin your work product.
- You may end up with a suction condition where the heat of the furnace drives the air out into the sea, in a hot pulse, then is sealed off by the water, pressure drops, and air is pulled in without you having to push a bellows.

  - Does the pulsing effect the quality of the smelt?
- There's no way (unless the shell is transparent) to inspect what's going on. I imagine the use case is to start one of these up and hope that it works, which isn't far different than bloomeries.
- Starting will be tricky. Too much air and you'll put the fire out. Too little air, and the fire will be choked out by exhaust gasses.
- Restarting after a failed start will be laborious. You'll want to keep air running through the bellows after a failed start for some amount of time to dilute the exhaust gas trapped inside with fresh air.

None of these problems seem insurmountable with enough patience.

Comment: "*700 to 800 C (for working with glass and soft metals). That's probably at least **35 times** the mean temperature of the surrounding sea water (17 C).*" is completely wrong.. 700C is only 3.3 times the temperature of 17C

Comment: According to my calculator 17 x 3.3 = 56

Comment: 17C is 290 Kelvin.  700C is 973Kelvin.. 973/290 = 3.355    Gas laws, and temperature, are barely literate. They only speak Kelvin, none of these silly humano-centric temperature scales.

Comment: Ah. Thank you .

Comment: You DO have a very valid point about that airspace pumping itself in and out with temperature. I'm also concerned with the absolute pressure, if that thing starts at even 100m down, the air density (and thus heat capacity) will be almost 10 times greater. Pretty soon cooling will be a real problem, along with heat loss from the work area.

Comment: Tak look at the sketch. Use difference of temperatures not division, if u mean heat loss., if not then use full K approach

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for the tips

Comment: Ahhh, nooow it makes sense, didn't caugth it back then, that volume reduction. The guy need to pump a lot of fuel and oxidiser to make heat,  so pumping a little for cooling process what for a problem is that, lol. Calculating water colums is probably excessive. "to be quick" it will take hours to cool, and all that space is not necessarly that hot if u imagine big bell volume - as any building in which furnance is installed, people work next to them. Hm if your point was to exagregate problems, then it probably a good answer, hm

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the smelter works by burning some combustible, the main problem I see is that you lack a way of extracting combustion gases, which are hot and loaded with CO2.

CO2, if not removed, will quickly set off the combustion by removing all the oxygen. If you instead keep pumping air in, you will reach a point where either the pressure is too high for the structure to withstand or you won't be able to push any more air in.

If you set the outlet pipes in counterflow with the inlet you can preheat the combustion air, which adds some optimization to the whole smelting, since you won't have to use the combustible to heat up the air.

Comment: How do you mean "set off the combustion"? I'm assuming that you mean that the burning will stop because of lack of oxigen, cooling it all down, but you might mean something different.

Comment: Excess CO2 is only an issue for the operator, not the fire. As long as the fire gets sufficient O2, it does not matter too much what the rest of the gasses in the mix are.(will affect the alloys, but this is much lesser concern). Heat buildup is a concern. Breathability of the air in there is a big concern, but i suspect the operator does not breathe air. This could work, in a horridly inefficient and clumsy way. Pressure may be an issue, hope this is not *too* deep down.

Comment: @PcMan, that's why I added pressure build up. If air keeps being pumped in with nothing going out, pressure will rise

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica  How will pressure rise(beyond pressure at bottom of container)?  The gas/air portion is not in a sealed container. It is open to the water. With that design the gas chamber will just overflow at some point as more gas is added.

Answer (score 1):

### It will work but not well.

1. It will only produce small amounts since you are limited by the shell size, most of a smelters mass insulation.
2. It will be slow as molasses, since you will have to stop airflow, wait for the smelter to cool completely , then restart airflow to access the smelter.
3. it can explode, you need to toughly dry the material before you start or you have a steam bomb, this will take days of low level heating, which will be tricky to achieve. if you try to fire pottery in it this is an even bigger problem.
4. the shells are single use, don't expect the shells to last through many smeltings. You are superheating the inside of the shell which causes calcium carbonate to break down into lime which will react violently with water. As a bonus it creates a ready supply of water purification and food preserving agent (slaked lime), just don't let your workers breath or swim in the water.